# How to add custom column to grid of customers in admin?

Tags: magento2

How to add custom column to grid of customers in admin ?

Can anyone help me?

I need to add a checkbox for each customer so that the administrator can suspend the customer account by clicking on the checkbox and back

[image]

Comment: check from here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221765/magento-2-add-attribute-to-customer-grid

Comment: I need to add value from customer grid

Comment: Add the **visible** item in your config item, like this
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>